# What is the behavoir of atexit() in a dll/so loaded at runtime?

Tags: c++, dll, shared-libraries

If I load a dll/so file at runtime (i.e. using `LoadLibrary()` or `dlopen()`), what is the behavior of the C++ `atexit()` function? Does it get called if I unload the library before the application exits? And can I expect the same behavior on all platforms? (Specifically, windows and unix-like systems)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under windows: when you call FreeLibrary then for each dll there will be executed `atexit` functions chain. It is important to note that dll's gets unloaded in unspecified order so do not add `atexit` handlers that depends on some other dll's globals.

Here is some more info link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/988ye33t.aspx